# Loading a RecylerView within another RecyclerView Item android Java

Tags: java, android, json

Is there a simplest way of Doing this , while using Nested JSON objects (JSON object with JSON ArrayObjects)

This is my JSON data

```
[
  {
    "Cinemax": "Blue Ray",
    "Contacts": "0704594180",
    "CinemaxPhoto": "huzy.jpg",
    "Longitude": "32.89577584",
    "Latitude": "0.46378484",
    "Movie": [
      {
        "MovieName": "Ice Age 3",
        "Synopsis": "Manny, Diego and sid",
        "photo": "ice_age_3.jpg",
        "others": null,
        "ShowTime": {
          "Monday": "1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
          "Tuesday": "1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m",
          "Wednesday": "1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m",
          "Thursday": "1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m",
          "Friday": "1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m",
          "Saturday": "1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m",
          "Sunday": "1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"
        }
      },
      {
        "MovieName": "Zootopia",
        "Synopsis": "Manny, Diego and sid",
        "photo": "zootopia.jpg",
        "others": null,
        "ShowTime": {
          "Monday": "4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
          "Tuesday": "4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
          "Wednesday": "4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
          "Thursday": "4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
          "Friday": "4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
          "Saturday": "4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
          "Sunday": "4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m"
        }
      },
      {
        "MovieName": "Madaari",
        "Synopsis": "Nirmal loses his family in a man-made disaster, he starts the journey of seeking answers asking for accountabilty, for sure am a genius , lets try out and see whether this will work out, horaay , i dont know , me am confused ",
        "photo": "madaari.jpg",
        "others": null,
        "ShowTime": {
          "Monday": "6:30 p.m , 8:30 p.m",
          "Tuesday": "6:30 p.m , 8:30 p.m",
          "Wednesday": "6:30 p.m , 8:30 p.m",
          "Thursday": "6:30 p.m , 8:30 p.m",
          "Friday": "6:30 p.m , 8:30 p.m",
          "Saturday": "6:30 p.m , 8:30 p.m",
          "Sunday": "6:30 p.m , 8:30 p.m"
        }
      },
      {
        "MovieName": "Me Before You",
        "Synopsis": "A girl in a small town forms an unlikely bond with a recently paralyzed man she is taking care of.",
        "photo": "me_before_you.jpg",
        "others": null,
        "ShowTime": {
          "Monday": "8:30 p.m , 11:30 p.m",
          "Tuesday": "8:30 p.m , 11:30 p.m",
          "Wednesday": "8:30 p.m , 11:30 p.m",
          "Thursday": "8:30 p.m , 11:30 p.m",
          "Friday": "8:30 p.m , 11:30 p.m",
          "Saturday": "8:30 p.m , 11:30 p.m",
          "Sunday": "8:30 p.m , 11:30 p.m"
        }
      },
      {
        "MovieName": "Ghostbusters",
        "Synopsis": "Following a ghost invasion of Manhattan, paranormal enthusiasts Erin Gilbert and Abby Yates , nuclear engineer jillian Holtzmann",
        "photo": "ghost_busters.jpg",
        "others": null,
        "ShowTime": {
          "Monday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Tuesday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Wednesday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Thursday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Friday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Saturday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Sunday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Cinemax": "White Down",
    "Contacts": "0700304850",
    "CinemaxPhoto": "hello.jpg",
    "Longitude": "32.89577584",
    "Latitude": "0.46378484",
    "Movie": [
      {
        "MovieName": "The Legend Of Tarzan",
        "Synopsis": "Tarzan , having acclimated to life in London, is called back to his former home in the jungle to investigate",
        "photo": "legend_of_tarzan.jpg",
        "others": null,
        "ShowTime": {
          "Monday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Tuesday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Wednesday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Thursday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Friday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Saturday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m",
          "Sunday": "11:30 p.m , 1:30 a.m"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My First Activity which successfully loaded the First RecyclerView

```
package oerrride.we.huzykamz.ugentapp;


        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
        import android.net.NetworkInfo;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import adapters.CinemaAdapter;

public class Cinemas extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewExample";
    private List<ItemObjects> feedsList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CinemaAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cinemas);


        //

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Cinemax List");


        // Initialize recycler view
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Downloading data from below url

// internet connectivity........
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();




        final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/UgandaEntertainment/Cinema/fetch.php";
            if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
            }
        else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"No network connection! , please check your connectivity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                // 200 represents HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    result = 1; // Successful
                } else {
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Download complete. Let us update UI
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (result == 1) {
                adapter = new CinemaAdapter(Cinemas.this, feedsList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Cinemas.this, "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {

            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(result);

            feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                ItemObjects item = new ItemObjects();

                item.setCinemaName(obj.optString("Cinemax"));
                item.setContact(obj.optString("Contacts"));
                item.setCinemaxPhoto(obj.optString("CinemaxPhoto"));
                item.setLongitude(obj.optString("Longitude"));
                item.setLatitude(obj.optString("Latitude"));


                //Here you have another Movie Json Array so get it in JSONArray
                JSONArray movieArray =obj.getJSONArray("Movie");


                //get the first object of Movie  JSONArray and use it.
                JSONObject movieObject=movieArray.getJSONObject(0);


                item.setMovieName(movieObject.optString("MovieName"));

                //This JSOn object to get SHOWTIME object
                JSONObject showTime=movieObject.getJSONObject("ShowTime");

                item.setMonday(showTime.optString("Monday"));
                item.setTuesday(showTime.optString("Tuesday"));
                item.setWednesday(showTime.optString("Wednesday"));
                item.setThursday(showTime.optString("Thursday"));
                item.setFriday(showTime.optString("Friday"));
                item.setSaturday(showTime.optString("Saturday"));
                item.setSunday(showTime.optString("Sunday"));

                item.setSynopsis(movieObject.optString("Synopsis"));
                item.setPhoto(movieObject.optString("photo"));



                feedsList.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter Class which Sends Data to the Nest Activity

```
package adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import oerrride.we.huzykamz.ugentapp.CinemaViewHolders;
import oerrride.we.huzykamz.ugentapp.ItemObjects;
import oerrride.we.huzykamz.ugentapp.LoadingMovies;
import oerrride.we.huzykamz.ugentapp.R;

/**
 * Created by HUZY_KAMZ on 7/22/2016.
 */
public class CinemaAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CinemaViewHolders> {
    String url="http://10.0.2.2/UgandaEntertainment/CinemaPics/";
    private List<ItemObjects> itemList = null;
    private Context context;


    private ArrayList<ItemObjects> arraylist;
    public CinemaAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObjects> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CinemaViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cinema_list,parent,false);
        CinemaViewHolders rcv = new CinemaViewHolders(layoutView,context);
        return rcv;
    }
    public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immagex=image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        // Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
        return imageEncoded;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CinemaViewHolders holder,final int position) {
      final  ItemObjects feedItems = itemList.get(position);

        holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //


                Intent intent = new Intent(CinemaAdapter.this.context, LoadingMovies.class);
                intent.putExtra(CinemaViewHolders.KEY_MOVIE_NAME, feedItems.getMovieName());
                intent.putExtra(CinemaViewHolders.KEY_MOVIE_IMAGE, feedItems.getPhoto());
               //

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Download image using picasso library
        Picasso.with(context).load(url+feedItems.getCinemaxPhoto())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder).
                resize(500,500)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(holder.countryPhoto);

        holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getCinemaName());




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemList ? itemList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

I have Successfuly retrieved the list of Cinemax `Cinemax`object and `CinemaxPhoto`object in the first Recycler view. Now i want when an item is Clicked to load Another RecyclerView , Containing the Relevant Information on the Cinemax.

Below is my `SecondActivity` which is trying  to  load `MovieName` Object and `photo` , `ShowTime` Object , but it doesnt bring matching information per each Cinemax.

Is there something i have to edit in `parseResult` method in the **SecondActivity**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapters.CinemaAdapter;
import adapters.LoadingMoviesAdapter;

public class LoadingMovies extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewExample";
    private List<ItemObjects> feedsList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LoadingMoviesAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
   private String  moviename="MovieName";
    private String moviepic ="photo";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ntinda);


        //

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Now Showing Ntinda ");



        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String imageString=extras.getString(NtindaCinemaViewHolders.KEY_MOVIE_IMAGE);





        // Initialize recycler view
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
      /*  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));*/


        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return (3 - position % 4);
            }
        });




        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Downloading data from below url

// internet connectivity........
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();




        final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/UgandaEntertainment/Cinema/fetch.php";
        if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"No network connection! , please check your connectivity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                // 200 represents HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    result = 1; // Successful
                } else {
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Download complete. Let us update UI
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (result == 1) {
                adapter = new LoadingMoviesAdapter(LoadingMovies.this, feedsList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoadingMovies.this, "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {

            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(result);

            feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                ItemObjects item = new ItemObjects();

                // declaring bundle

                // what should i put here to access the movies and showTime????

                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

                moviename = bundle.getString(CinemaViewHolders.KEY_MOVIE_NAME);
                moviepic = bundle.getString(CinemaViewHolders.KEY_MOVIE_IMAGE);


                        ItemObjects huxy = new ItemObjects();


                JSONArray movieArray =obj.getJSONArray("Movie");


                //get the first object of Movie  JSONArray and use it.
                JSONObject movieObject=movieArray.getJSONObject(0);


                item.setMovieName(movieObject.optString(moviename));

                //This JSON object to get SHOWTIME object
                JSONObject showTime=movieObject.getJSONObject("ShowTime");


                item.setPhoto(movieObject.optString("photo"));



                feedsList.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample of your JSON data ,and How would you like to display?

Comment: I have posted the code @Jamal , please its up , have a look

Comment: Please help me out @Jamal

Comment: What do want to display in the second activity?

Comment: I want also the SecondActivity to Load another RecyclerView containing movies after clicking any of the Cinemax from the FisrtActivity, but the problem i dont know how to deal with the JSONArray which is parsed to the SecondACtivity

Comment: while maintaining the position of each item

Comment: I don't know why you are loading the movies again in the second activity as I see from your json structure you have a list of cinemas and every cinema has a list of movies. Then you don't need to load them gain just pass them to the second activity as  a Parcable and display them directly in a RecyclerView

Comment: Yeah its true @Jamal, but am new in this stuff , can you give me a sample of passing data as a Parcable in a recycler\View, thanks

Comment: Please help me out @Jamal (akhi)